# Klevu Template Override

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I am new to magneto 2 and we are using klevu search engine for search functionality. I would like to add custom text to that template. If anybody has a succession, please help me,

Answer (score 1):

For details on the customisation,Please visit the Klevu template JS document using the link below:
https://docs.klevu.com/template-js

Also, if you have a specific question, please reach out to the Klevu community using the below link:
https://community.klevu.com/